# Can you use Powershell in Windows Server 2008 to Delegate Control over Organizational Units?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

How can I use PowerShell in Window Server 2008 to delegate control of an Organizational Unit? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Quest ActiveRoles cmdlets, they are a great extension to your powershell library when working with AD. There is a specific cmdlet for ADPermissions there, but it will probably take some trial and error to get your permissions right. It's a good starting point, though.